# Generating models for Flask-AppBuilder using flask-sqlqcodegen

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm a beginner in Python and Flask ecosystems, trying to create a small proof-of-concept Web application for a research project. I'm using Debian Linux 7.9, PostgreSQL 9.5, SQLAlchemy (latest) and Flask-AppBuilder (latest). Since creating models manually is tedious and error-prone, I searched the mighty Internet and discovered the `flask-sqlacodegen` project (note that this a fork of `sqlacodegen` with improved features for Flask users). I installed `flask-sqlqcodegen` from GitHub (cloned repo and then ran `python setup.py install`). However, when trying to use it to generate models, it produces an error, as follows:

```
> sqlacodegen postgresql+psycopg2://USER:PASS@HOST/DBNAME --flask

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sqlacodegen", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('sqlacodegen==1.1.5.pre2', 'console_scripts', 'sqlacodegen')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlacodegen-1.1.5.pre2-py2.7.egg/sqlacodegen/main.py", line 57, in main
    args.flask, fkcols)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlacodegen-1.1.5.pre2-py2.7.egg/sqlacodegen/codegen.py", line 597, in __init__
    model = ModelClass(table, links[table.name], inflect_engine, not nojoined)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlacodegen-1.1.5.pre2-py2.7.egg/sqlacodegen/codegen.py", line 319, in __init__
    relationship_ = ManyToOneRelationship(self.name, target_cls, constraint, inflect_engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlacodegen-1.1.5.pre2-py2.7.egg/sqlacodegen/codegen.py", line 455, in __init__
    colname = constraint.columns[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 194, in __getitem__
    return self._data[key]
KeyError: 0
```

What is going on? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Upon some Internet searching, I ran across an issue on GitHub, which described exactly the same problem. However, the most recent recommendation at the time produced another error instead of the original one. In the [discussion](https://github.com/ksindi/flask-sqlacodegen/issues/8) with the author of `flask-sqlcodegen`, it appeared that there exist a pull request (PR) kindly provided by a project contributor that apparently should fix the problem. After updating my local repository, followed by rebuilding and reinstalling the software, I was able to successfully generate models for my database. The whole process consists of the following steps.

1. Change to directory with a local repo of `flask-sqlcodegen`.
2. If you made any changes, like I did, stash them: `git stash`.
3. Update repo: `git pull origin master` (now includes that PR).
4. Rebuild/install software: `python setup.py install`.
5. If you need your prior changes, restore them: `git stash pop`. Otherwise, discard them: `git reset --hard`.
6. Change to your Flask application directory and auto-generate the models, as follows.

   `sqlacodegen --flask --outfile models.py postgresql+psycopg2://USER:PASS@HOST/DBNAME`

**Acknowledgements:** Big thank you to Kamil Sindi (the `flask-sqlcodegen`'s author) for the nice software and rapid & helpful feedback as well as to Alisdair Venn for that valuable pull request.