# Flask: application unable to run because of KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Am currently studying how to develop web applications using `Flask` and i was following [this](https://damyanon.net/tags/flask/) tutorial on how to do it and everything was moving on fine till the concept of Flask-SQLAchemy got introduced.

The structure of my flask application is as below

```
├── bin
├── bookshelf
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── controllers.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── controllers.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
├── config.py
├── data-dev.sqlite
├── docs
├── requirements.txt
├── run.py
```

Am trying to use an sqlite database(`data-dev.sqlite`) that i designed myself without having to go through the process of `SQLAchemy` creating for me one and below is it's structure; that was generated using the `.dump` command in sqlite

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE author (
id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
author_names VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE book (
id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
rating INT,
image VARCHAR(30),
author_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES author(id)
);
CREATE TABLE role (
id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
role_name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
description VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE user (
id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
email VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
active BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
role_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES role(id)
);
COMMIT;
```

The traceback produced when i run the command `python run.py runserver -d` in the `venv` is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bookshelf import create_app
  File "/home/mayatsa/environments/flask-test/bookshelf/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bookshelf.main.controllers import main
  File "/home/mayatsa/environments/flask-test/bookshelf/main/controllers.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bookshelf.data.models import Author, Book
  File "/home/mayatsa/environments/flask-test/bookshelf/data/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Book(db.Model):
  File "/home/mayatsa/environments/flask-test/bookshelf/data/models.py", line 8, in Book
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['book']
KeyError: 'book'
```

Files order of traceback from top to bottom and their contents are as follows

**run.py**

```
from bookshelf import create_app
from flask_script import Manager

app = create_app()
manager = Manager(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

**bookshelf/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from bookshelf.main.controllers import main
from bookshelf.admin.controllers import admin
from bookshelf.data.models import db

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config')

    with app.app_context():
        db.init_app(app)
        db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)

    app.register_blueprint(main, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(admin, url_prefix='/admin')

    return app
```

**bookshelf/main/controllers.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request
from bookshelf.data.models import Author, Book

main = Blueprint('main', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@main.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('main/index.html')

@main.route('books/')
def display_books():
    return render_template('main/books.html')
```

**bookshelf/data/models.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Book(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['book']
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Book %r>' % (self.title)

class Author(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['author']
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Author %r>' % (self.author_names)

class Role(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['role']
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Role %r>' % (self.role_name)

class User(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['user']

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.email)
```

Additional **config.py**

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = True
TESTING = False
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
    'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data-dev.sqlite')
SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN = True
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
SECRET_KEY = 'a9eec0e0-23b7-4788-9a92-318347b9a39f'
```

From all the code provided above, what could be causing my application to produce this error and stopping it from running?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I kept probing till i landed on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693704/accessing-existing-database-in-sqlalchemy-in-flask-project-sqlalchemy-filter?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657634/generating-models-for-flask-appbuilder-using-flask-sqlqcodegen) and they helped clear up the fog for me.

After installing [sqlacodegen](https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen) and [flask-sqlacodegen](https://github.com/ksindi/flask-sqlacodegen) using

```
pip install sqlacodegen
pip install flask-sqlacodegen
```

All i had to do now is run the following command in my `Flask` application root

```
sqlacodegen sqlite:///data-dev.sqlite --flask > models.py
```

And the models corresponding to my database were generated and then after i replaced my the `bookshelf/data/models.py` with the just generated `models.py`.

Then finally changed `bookshelf/__init__.py` **create_app** function to look like this

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config')

    db.init_app(app)

    app.register_blueprint(main, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(admin, url_prefix='/admin')

    return app
```

And now everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `models.py` file is executed before the tables are reflected. In `bookshelf/__init__.py` file, you're importing your controllers main and admin at the top, which in turn import your data models from `bookshelf/data/models.py` which subclasses the SQLAlchemy instance db. But the `db.reflect()` is yet to happen, therefore the metadata of the tables isn't reflecting and hence the key error. To solve this, either import your models in your controllers inside the functions, wherever needed, like this

**bookshelf/main/controllers.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request

main = Blueprint('main', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@main.route('/')
def index():
    from bookshelf.data.models import Author, Book
    return render_template('main/index.html')

@main.route('books/')
def display_books():
    from bookshelf.data.models import Book
    return render_template('main/books.html')
```

or import your controllers after you've initialized your db object like this,

**bookshelf/**init**.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from bookshelf.data.models import db

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config')

    with app.app_context():
        db.init_app(app)
        db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)

    from bookshelf.admin.controllers import admin, main
    app.register_blueprint(main, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(admin, url_prefix='/admin')

    return app
```

After this, just add a separate `database.py` file to create the SQLAlchemy object instead of creating it in your `models.py` file, since it will cause a circular import issue if you have it in either `bookshelf/init.py` or `bookshelf/data/models.py`.

**bookshelf/database.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Remove this line from your **init**.py file

`from bookshelf.data.models import db`

and instead get it in your **init**.py from database.py

`from bookshelf.database import db`

Answer (score -1):

The metadata isn't there yet at the time you're importing `bookshelf.data.models`, as it's being reflected into the metadata only afterwards.

Maybe using `__tablename__` instead of `__table__` might help? I'm not that well versed in the intricacies of SQLAlchemy.

Comment: it still generates the same output

Comment: If you use `__tablename__ = 'book'`, for instance?

Comment: when i do that it gives me this message `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|Book|book could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'book'`